# Which image should I use on AWS China?

Tags: server, cloud, amazon-ec2, aws

I want to run Ubuntu on EC2 in [AWS china](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/)

The ubuntu [Amazon EC2 AMI Locator](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) does list some AMIs in the china regions... but they don't seem to be available.

Are there any official Ubuntu AMIs pushed to AWS China?

There seems to be somewhat official looking AMIs pushed to account number 837727238323, but I can't work out who owns this account, thus I don't feel comfortable using them unless I know these images are pushed by someone I can trust.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any official Ubuntu AMIs pushed to AWS China?

The instances listed in your link are the official ones.

> thus I don't feel comfortable

Why? You should assume -all- instances are monitored, copied and viewed by the Chinese government.

The list from `drift-aws` is 2 numbers, one is official Canonical but excludes China and the other is for China. Because of the 1st number I would assume the 2nd is official too.

```
# Pick either one!
OWNERID=099720109477  # All regions except China, https://www.canonical.com/
OWNERID=837727238323  # China, some Ubuntu user. Who knows. Hopefully Canonical.
```

This is likely to comply with Chinese law: only citizens are allowed to own a business in China. Outsiders need to appoint a citizen to be owner of that company.

I can find 837727238323 at [apcera-orchestrator-20190327 (ami-0cdbde1f9ee4b4704)](https://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-0cdbde1f9ee4b4704--apcera-orchestrator-20190327), and [continuum-base-20190327 (ami-03bd834b5b06063b7)](https://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-03bd834b5b06063b7--continuum-base-20190327). Both are not from Canonical (the am i is not listed on the site) and not China but Asia Pacific Singapore.

Besides that... there are no other numbers and only 1 for China.

Comment: Joint-ventures are allowed. That's how China makes more cars than Japan, USA and Germany combined now.

Comment: Yeah I saw the list from drift-aws and "some Ubuntu user. Who knows. Hopefully Canonical." didn't fill me with confidence ...

I get that running in China is subject to the Chinese Government rules ... but that doesn't mean I should say ... no one knows who made this image so YOLO ...

Comment: @EdwardRobinson prepare for the ami to disappear :D We lost gcloud instances 10 times in the past 5 years.